# How does react hooks handles callback when it sets the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In a class-based component when one would set the state, it would take the argument of the new state and sometimes one could fire another function within it. In a functional-based component, using hooks, how can I accomplish the same goal?

```
// class-based componenet example:

state = {
  count: 0
}

this.setState({
  count: count +1
}, () => someFunction())


// functional-based componenet example:(how to fire someFunction() when the state is set like in the class-based componenet?)

const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

setCount(count +1)
```

I'm aware that hooks don't take a second argument but can something similar be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think the useEffect hook would help you here. It basically acts as a componentDidUpdate:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    doSomething();
  }, [count]);
```

The second parameter means that the effect / function will only fire if count changes.

Comment: So would I be able to useEffect twice with the same function, first time would be for when my page loads. And the second time would be for when the dependency is met?

Comment: You can have as many useEffects as you'd like, just know that they will be called whenever a state change is detected.